# Connect to your server from different networks

Tags: php, android, hosting, lamp

I am building an android application and I am using lamp on Ubuntu to host a server on my machine. I'm new to this and I don't know if there is any way to connect to my server from different networks.

To connect to my local server I am using my ip like this:

```
http://myipHere/android/update.php
```

When trying to connect with my phone from the same network it works but it doesn't work when connecting from others.

Is it possible to connect from different networks to my host?

Comment: Yes of course. The client should use the internet ip of the router where your server is connected to. On the router forward the used port to the server computer.

Comment: Fixed general formatting

Answer (score 0):

Only way to do this using PORT FORWARDING. use this link: http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-Port-Forwarding-on-a-Router